# Aligning the reference centred on the heading

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, align

I have a problem. The reference under the list of tables and list of figures is not centred on the heading. It is slightly indented, like with a tab (see the first photo). The second photo shows how it should look.

[image]

[image]

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% added
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}

....

\clearpage
```

As soon as I use this solution with `\clearpage` after each section, the area between heading and header is differently larger.
For the normal headings the size is normal and for the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables the area between heading and header is larger.

However, what I want is that the reference List of Figures and List of Tables is aligned under the heading and the area between the heading and the header remains the same.

[image]

Complete document

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left={3.5cm}, right={2.5cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[driverfallback=hypertex]{hyperref} 
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering text in X column
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\ref{#1} \nameref{#1}}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = black, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = black, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor   = black %Colour of citations
}




\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{%
    \leavevmode
    \raise.9ex\hbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\normalfont\tiny\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% added
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}



\begin{document}
    



\pagenumbering{roman} % Nummeriung Römisch





\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\clearpage

% 
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\clearpage






\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Nummeriung Arabisch



\newpage



\chapter{Figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Three dimensional graph.}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\subsection{Table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 \hline
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 \hline
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 \hline
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 \hline
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{First table.}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
 \hline
 Country Name    or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 \\
 \hline
 Afghanistan & AF &AFG \\
 Aland Islands & AX & ALA \\
 Albania    &AL & ALB \\
 Algeria    &DZ & DZA \\
 American Samoa & AS & ASM \\
 Andorra & AD & AND \\
 Angola & AO & AGO \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Dummy table.}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | } 
  \hline
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
  cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
  cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Third table.}
\label{tab:table3}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your query correctly, you're looking to fix two separate issues.

- To left-align the entries in the list of figures and list of tables (or, Abbildungsverzeichnis and Tabellenverzeichnis, resp.), you could employ the machinery of the `tocloft` package, as follows:

  ```
  \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
  \setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
  \setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}
  ```
- To reduce the vertical distance between the header line and a chapter-level header in the body of the document to match the vertical distance between the header line and a section-level header, I suggest you change

  ```
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-29pt}{15pt}
  ```

---

Here's an adaptation of your code that implements these ideas.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, vmargin=3cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-29pt}{15pt} %%{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering in X column

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\ref{#1} \nameref{#1}}


\usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage[driverfallback=hypertex]{hyperref} % don't load package twice
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, % Colored text instead of ugly boxes
    allcolors    = black
%    urlcolor     = black, %Colour for external hyperlinks
%    linkcolor    = black, %Colour of internal links
%    citecolor    = black %Colour of citations
}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{%
    \leavevmode
    \raise.9ex\hbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\normalfont\tiny\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% (now enabled)
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}




\begin{document}

%% front matter

\pagenumbering{roman} % Nummeriung Römisch
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables



%% main matter

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Nummeriung Arabisch



\chapter{A figure and three tables}

\section{A figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. 

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A three-dimensional graph.}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.



\clearpage
\section{Three tables}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 \hline
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 \hline
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 \hline
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 \hline
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{First table.}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
 \hline
 Country Name    or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 \\
 \hline
 Afghanistan & AF &AFG \\
 Aland Islands & AX & ALA \\
 Albania    &AL & ALB \\
 Algeria    &DZ & DZA \\
 American Samoa & AS & ASM \\
 Andorra & AD & AND \\
 Angola & AO & AGO \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Dummy table.}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | } 
  \hline
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
  cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
  cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Third table.}
\label{tab:table3}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked! I really appreciate it, thanks agian.

Comment: I have one more question, if I only insert the following code snippets `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} ...` and `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-29pt}{15pt}`, it does not work. However, if I add the code 1:1 it works. Is there anything else that has been added? Or is the order of the imports crucial?

Comment: @Test - Are you running the two `\setlength` instructions?

Comment: Yes I am running `\setlength` @Mico

Comment: the problem was that I was loading twice the package.